# Unity Facebook SDK: FB.Feed not posting

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I finished my game. Now I want to make it social. Posting to twitter is easy, but I have a problem with facebook.

I created an app on facebook dev, I have key-hash, key-store, I don't have any errors in console. I made enviroment variables with paths to JDK and OpenSSL.
Maybe there's something wrong with my code (it's from SDK example) but I don't know what.

This script is attached to NGUI button. In editor it works but on device it only asks to login and permission. Then nothing happens.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public sealed class FacebookShare : MonoBehaviour {
#region FB.Init() example

private bool isInit = false;

void Awake ()
{
    CallFBInit();
}

private void CallFBInit()
{
    FB.Init(OnInitComplete, OnHideUnity);
}

private void OnInitComplete()
{
    Debug.Log("FB.Init completed: Is user logged in? " + FB.IsLoggedIn);
    isInit = true;
}

private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
{
    Debug.Log("Is game showing? " + isGameShown);
}

#endregion

#region FB.Login() example

private void CallFBLogin()
{
    FB.Login("email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);
}

void LoginCallback(FBResult result)
{
    if (result.Error != null)
        lastResponse = "Error Response:\n" + result.Error;
    else if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        lastResponse = "Login cancelled by Player";
    }
    else
    {
        lastResponse = "Login was successful!";
    }
}

private void CallFBLogout()
{
    FB.Logout();
}
#endregion

#region FB.Feed() example

public string FeedToId = "";
public string FeedLink = "";
public string FeedLinkName = "";
public string FeedLinkCaption = "";
public string FeedLinkDescription = "";
public string FeedPicture = "";
public string FeedMediaSource = "";
public string FeedActionName = "";
public string FeedActionLink = "";
public string FeedReference = "";
public bool IncludeFeedProperties = false;
private Dictionary<string, string[]> FeedProperties = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

private void CallFBFeed()
{
    Dictionary<string, string[]> feedProperties = null;
    if (IncludeFeedProperties)
    {
        feedProperties = FeedProperties;
    }
    FB.Feed(
        toId: FeedToId,
        link: FeedLink,
        linkName: FeedLinkName,
        linkCaption: FeedLinkCaption,
        linkDescription: FeedLinkDescription,
        picture: FeedPicture,
        mediaSource: FeedMediaSource,
        actionName: FeedActionName,
        actionLink: FeedActionLink,
        reference: FeedReference,
        properties: feedProperties,
        callback: Callback
        );
}

#endregion
public string ApiQuery = "";
private string lastResponse = "";
private Texture2D lastResponseTexture;

void Callback(FBResult result)
{
    lastResponseTexture = null;
    // Some platforms return the empty string instead of null.
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
        lastResponse = "Error Response:\n" + result.Error;
    else if (!ApiQuery.Contains("/picture"))
        lastResponse = "Success Response:\n" + result.Text;
    else
    {
        lastResponseTexture = result.Texture;
        lastResponse = "Success Response:\n";
    }
}

void OnClick ()
{
    CallFBLogin();
    CallFBFeed();
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried running the 'InteractiveConsole' example scene built into the SDK? (also, as @sat mentioned below, you have to wait until login succeeds to call fb feed).

Comment: @aaron Yes, I tried and it works perfectly in the editor, but on device it only asks to login and permission. Then nothing happens.

Comment: can you post a logcat file of what happens when you try to run? also, we just released a new v6 SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads maybe give that a quick try if you're not on that version.

Comment: @aaron I installed new SDK, but it didn't help. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/Wc5qcP4.png)'s what happen after after logging.

Comment: @aaron Oh it seems like I made a verry stupid mistake :) I thought "Feed to Id" should be the App Id. I left it empty and now it works! Thank you for help anyway.

Comment: glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

You trying to feed before LoginCallback called. Try to change your LoginCallback and OnClick functions something like this:

```
   void LoginCallback(FBResult result) {
        if (result.Error != null)
            lastResponse = "Error Response:\n" + result.Error;
        else if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            lastResponse = "Login cancelled by Player";
        }
        else
        {
            lastResponse = "Login was successful!";
            CallFBFeed();
        }
    }
    void OnClick ()
    {
       CallFBLogin();
    }
```

Comment: It didn't help. Now It doesn't work in editor too (I think it worked only for the first time). Maybe it's something with keyhash? Now it uses the debug.keystore. Maybe I should use keyhash form my keystore that I created fot my game?

Comment: Sorry for later response. Yes, you must put your debug keyhash in "Android/Key Hashes" field in the settings tab of your application on facebook developer console. And then do not forget to do that for release key.